# Android antialiasing and pixel snapping

Tags: android, android-layout, pixel, antialiasing

I have a simple ListView with 1 dip border around cells. But depending on position they renders as 1 оr 2 pixel height. As I understand it is due to antialiasing - 1 dip line renders as 1 pixel only if it has precisely integer position. But in ListView scrolling position have floating point representation so line width jittering occurs during scroll even if cell heights are exactly integer.

Is there any way to do "pixel snapping" in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am guessing a bit, but your description sounds more like you have automatic scaling turned on (which it is by default). Suggest you try adding this tag as a child of your <manifest> tag in AndroidManifest.xml, if you haven't done so already.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: It's ok now but now needs some revision of code to reconcile some sizes. Thank you!